# .htaccess main page

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect any non-existing URL back to its main page.

Below is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add that:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.[^/.]{3,4})/.* $1 [R=301,L]
```

And no need to use more than one `RewriteEngine on` for all the .htaccess.

Comment: Yes, I had not clearly understood the problem. Now look at my edited code.

Comment: Try to add before `# To internally forward...`